# Python not able to read "–" character from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Using Python, I am fetching some text data from an API and storing it in a text file after some transformations and then reading this text file from a different process.

There are no problems while reading data from API, but I am getting this error while reading the text file:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 907: invalid start byte
```

The byte being read as '0x96' is actually "–" character in API data and this error occurs only when `encoding` argument is explicitly specified as `'utf-8'`. It doesn't occur when `encoding` is not explicitly passed to `open` function while opening the text file.

**My questions:**

1. Why do we get this error only when `encoding` is specified? I think, we should get the same error in other case as well since default encoding is also 'UTF-8'. (Please correct me if I am wrong)
2. Is it possible to resolve this issue without changing the way I am reading the text file? (i.e. Can I make any changes to the stage where I am creating this text file from API data?)

Really appreciate you looking into it. Thanks!

Comment: what do you get when you change the encoding to `latin1`?

Comment: @stefan_mit_hannover, No errors, but it is being read as '\x96'

Comment: and you specify some encoding when storing the text?

Comment: @Copperfield, I was under assumption that it is 'utf-8' by default, so I did not specify any encoding before posting this question. Then I got to know from the accepted answer that default encoding is system dependent. Now, I am using 'utf-8' encoding explicitly while writing the file and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `open()` the default encoding is platform dependent, you can find out what is the default for your system by checking what `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns. This is from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

For the 2nd part of your question, since you are not getting an error when you do not specify `utf-8` as encoding, you could just use the output for `locale.getpreferredencoding()` as the encoding method.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question perfectly. I am not using my system default encoding while writing the file, but I am going to use 'utf-8' since we are using the same while reading the file (and I didn't want to change that part). Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this for each line of the text if you are doing it this way. Since `0x96` is considered a "non-printable".

```
import re
...
line = re.sub(r'\x96',r'\x2D', line)
```

Comment: That should work, but I am going to consider @veedata's solution as ideal since it is more general (i.e. not just limited to one character). Thanks for the answer!